# How to implement multiple layout redirects for a login page and for other pages

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm stuck on implementing a login system where the login page is a separate layout which is also accessed by default if the user is not logged in. I read through some similar posts, but don't seem to know how to combine everything into a working solution.

My current setups are the following:

1. The Index page and a different page that have both a different layout

   ```
   @page "/"
   @model PartsModel //Should here be the Index Model?
   @{
      ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    }

   <div class="text-center">
     <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
     <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web APPS with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
   </div>
   ```

and a

```
@page "/MakeOrders"
@model PartsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Make Orders";
} 
<div>....</div>
```

2. The `_Viewstart.cshtml is the following

   ```
       @{
    var routeUrl = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Page"].ToString();
    var pages = new List<string> { "Login", string.Empty };
    if (pages.Any(routeUrl.Contains))
    {
        Layout = "_LoginLayout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
   ```

   }
3. The `Program.cs` file (omitted)

   ```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddCookie(options =>
                     {
                         options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                         // options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Access";
                         options.Cookie.Name = "AuthenticationCookie";
                         options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                         options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                     });
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endPoints =>
                     {
                         endPoints.MapRazorPages();
                         // Login
                         endPoints.MapControllerRoute(
                              name: "default",
                              pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                     });
   ```
4. The _LoginLayout.cshtml file itself:

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    .......
    <body>
        <partial name="_Login />
    </body>
    </html>
   ```
5. The _Login.cshtml file:

   ```
    @page "/Login"
    @model mOrders.Pages._LoginModel
    @{
        Layout = "_LoginLayout";
     }
   ```

Also I'd like to remove the Index Page but I am little lost as how to do this.
The errors I am currently getting are:
A circular layout reference was detected when rendering '/Pages/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml'. The layout page '/Pages/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml' has already been rendered, page crashed and issues related to the absence of the @RenderBody tag.

Comment: Have you checked this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi! It seems that this code does not use a controller which is my intention and also doesn't redirect the page if the user is already authenticated. I can't even do proper "startup" redirect with one layout let alone with 2 so I am a bit confused which task I should do first.

Comment: Above tutorial shows general steps to implement cookie-based authentication without using ASP.NET CORE identity, you can check the doc to know how cookie-based authentication works. And if you'd like to redirect user to different page instead of login page, you can redirect to another action or return specified view by specifying view name in your action method.

Comment: Ok, I will first to resolve the multiple layouts and the conditional redirection issue between the same layout and multiple lay, and the move on the login part.

Comment: I'm still running into issues. Can  you at least add step by step description of what should I do?

Comment: Also I am getting the error A circular layout reference was detected when rendering '/Pages/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml'. The layout page '/Pages/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml' has already been rendered.